# Converting text file to excel

Tags: excel

I have one text file as below:

```
word1  
word meaning  
word2  
word meaning
..... so on.
```

My intention is to convert this text file to excel file where one column will only have word names and another column will have meanings of the words.

```
Word1    Word Meaning  
Word2    Word Meaning  
Word3    Word Meaning
```

Is that possible ? I mean is there any technique available to do this?

Comment: do you have a bash or similar shell available?

Comment: Which language are you using ? You have to replace end of line every 2 lines. You can do it loading the file in a array (1 line = 1 item), and then rewrite the file you want

Comment: @WalterTross - I have command prompt. working on windows.

Comment: @ôkio I am not using any programming language to do so. I am trying to achieve it using only excel or direct method available if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the text file in Excel.  Your data will be in column A.  In B1 add the formula: `=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2-1)`, and in B2 add the formula: `=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2)`  Drag both cells down to get your new columns. Of course you'll only need to drag halfway down the length of your input column - below that you'll just get zeros.